# Validate input box is disabled in table rows - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a table with a column that has 3 buttons and one input box. Update, Save, Input box and Cancel. When we first enter the page, table is loaded with input box for all the rows as disabled. Only one button - Update is visible at that time (at each row). Once you click on Update, Input box becomes enabled (for that row), Update is hidden, save and cancel buttons are made visible. If either save or cancel is pressed, both buttons are hidden, again input box is disabled and Update is made visible. This is to ensure user enters the value in the input box and saves it properly.

Issue: if I click on update, and enter some random value. At this point if I save good, but if I dont save and under the table is a button to post data to backend, if I click that, the value I entered is passed to backend. I want to ensure, every row is validated to see that user has either saved/cancel and the input box is disabled (meaning the value entered is correct and final). How should I loop through this?

***View.xml***

```xml
<table:Column>
    <Label text="ABC"/>
    <table:template>
        <HBox alignItems="Center">
            <Button text="Update" visible="{path:'model>', formatter:'.updateBtnVisibility'}" press="openQtyInputBox"/>
            <Button text="Save" visible="{= !${model>qtyEditable}}" press="qtySave"/>
            <Input visible="{path:'model>', formatter:'.inputValidation'}" type="Number" enabled="{!${model>qtyEditable}}" value="{path: 'model>QtyToReceive', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer', constraints : {minimum: 0}}"/>
            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://reset" tooltip="Cancel" press="cancelQtyInput" visible="{= !${model>qtyEditable}}"/>
        </HBox>
    </table:template>
</table:Column>
```

Comment: what does the validation contain? you mean a data validation or a check to see if all input fields are set to `enabled = false` (which means all save/cancel buttons are hidden)?

Comment: Yes, @KristoffDT . All save/cancel butons are hidden, meaning all input boxes are enabled= false. This will ensure that user is not WIP with any row and has completed all input boxes.

Comment: in the model, you can check if there are any entries with qtyEditable == true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already store the input state in your model using `qtyEditable`. You can use this and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to loop through the contexts of the table rows:

```
validateRows: function() {
    var rowContexts = this.getView().byId("your-table-id").getBinding("rows").getContexts();

    if (rowContexts.filter(function (context) {
        return context.getProperty("qtyEditable");
    }).length === 0) {
        // all rows are saved
    } else {
        // at least one row is still in edit mode
    }
}
```